# Output content from one attribute based on another attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to generate an html tabel containing only content from the SDBTABLE and TNEWDATA if the SDBTABLE equals MYTABLE. Here is an example of my xml file. There will be many thousand ROW nodes with different SDBTABLE values.

```
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ID"><![CDATA[15310774]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="SUSERNAME"><![CDATA[SYSTEM]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="DCREATED"><![CDATA[13-12-17 09:01:30]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="SACTIONTYPE"><![CDATA[INSERT]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="SDBTABLE"><![CDATA[MYTABLE]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="TDATAORIGINAL"><![CDATA[]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="TNEWDATA"><![CDATA[VALUE1 = 36387 VALUE2 = '14600007515'
    VALUE3 = '20470361'
    VALUE4 = '22023453499'
    VALUE5 = null
    VALUE6 = null
    VALUE7 = null
    VALUE8 = null
    VALUE9 = '000034795'
    ]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="TWHERE"><![CDATA[]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

This is one of my many xsl attemps.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>MYTABLE</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>TABLE</th>
    <th>DATA</th>
   </tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="RESULTS/ROW">
    <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="COLUMN/@NAME='SDBTABLE'"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="COLUMN/@NAME='TNEWDATA'"/></td>
    </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Beside getting a result in the first place I would also like to extent the tabel with additional columns with the values from the TNEWDATA. I would like to be able to pin point the values that should be added like VALUE1, VALUE2 and VALUE9.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the initial requirement you're 99% of the way there already, just use `<xsl:value-of select="COLUMN[@NAME='SDBTABLE']" />`.

Comment: I have now also filtered with xsl:if but do you have any idea about how to get to the values in the TNEWDATA attribute